# Backup STM32 firmware using command line tools

Tags: backup, stm32, dump

I have a console STM32 ST-LINK utility. It is able to dump firmware to bin file. But the problem is in parameters. GUI version shows address and size in the upper "Memory display" groupbox. But how do I know the memory size parameter without GUI ST-LINK utility? Here is a parameter list for console version:
`-Dump<Address> <Memory_Size> <File_Path>`

Comment: You know what your micro model is so you know the size of the flash memory. What is the problem?

Comment: My firmware file sizes are about 20 kilobytes. Flash memory size is 1 megabyte. It means that I have to create backups with redundant constant size (if I use the same model)?

Answer (score 1):

Because you know your micro model you know the FLASH memory size and layout. ST-LINK utility does not provide any method of the chip identification

You can work it around by resetting the target first and saving the output to the file:

```
ST-LINK_CLI.exe -Rst 

STM32 ST-LINK CLI v3.2.0.0
STM32 ST-LINK Command Line Interface

ST-LINK SN : 0670FF485550755187194938
ST-LINK Firmware version : V2J29M18
Connected via SWD.
SWD Frequency = 4000K.
```

Then you can call another program (self written) to parse the result and get the uC model and memory size. Then you can execute the ST-LINK_CLI with the calculated parameters.
    Target voltage = 3.3 V.
    Connection mode : Normal.
    Device ID:0x449
    Device flash Size : 1024 Kbytes
    Device family :STM32F74x/F75x
    MCU Reset.

Comment: My firmware file sizes are about 20 kilobytes. Flash memory size is 1 megabyte. It means that I have to create backups with redundant constant size (if I use the same model)?